# Why moodledata directory has this structure?

Tags: moodle

I know moodle's internal files such as uploaded images are stored in `moodledata` directory.

Inside, there are several directories:

```
moodledata/filedir/1c/01/1c01d0b6691ace075042a14416a8db98843b0856
moodledata/filedir/63/
moodledata/filedir/63/89/
moodledata/filedir/63/89/63895ece79c4a91666312d0a24db82fe3017f54d
moodledata/filedir/63/3c/
moodledata/filedir/63/37/
moodledata/filedir/63/a7/
```

What are these hashses?

What are the design reasons behind this design, in oposition with, for example, wordpress `/year/month/file.jpg` structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/File_API_internals#File_storage_on_disk

Simple answer - files are stored based on the hash of their content (inspired by the way Git stores files internally).

This means that if you have the same file in multiple places (e.g. the same PDF or image in multiple courses), it is stored only once on the disk, even if the original filename is different.

On real sites this can involve a huge reduction in disk usage (obviously dependent on how much duplication there is on your site).

Answer (score 1):

Moodledata files are stored according to the SHA1 encoding of their content, in order to prevent the duplication of content (for example, when the same file is uploaded twice with a different name).

For further explanations of how to handle such files, you can read the official documentation of the File API :

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/File_API_internals

especially the `File storage on disk` part.